# Trying to place UILabel on top of UIButton in a custom UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel, uialertview

What I'm trying to do is place a `UILabel` on top of a `UIButton`.
The `UIButton` have an image as a background and the result is I cannot see the normal text on the `UIButton`, therefore I think to place the `UILabel` on top of it.

My code is:

```
NAlertView *customAlert = [[NAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:@"cancel", nil];
[customAlert show];
```

NAlertView.m:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    for (id obj in self.subviews) //Search in all sub views
    {

        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) // Override UIImageView (Background)
        { 
            UIImageView *imageView = obj;
            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CustomAlertView"]];
            [imageView setAlpha:0.7];
            [imageView sizeToFit];
        }

        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) // Override UILabel (Title, Text)
        {
            UILabel *label = (UILabel*)obj;

            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            label.shadowColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        }

        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) // Override the UIButton
        {
            UIButton *button = (UIButton*)obj;

            CGRect buttonFrame = button.frame; // Change UIButton size
            buttonFrame.size = CGSizeMake(127, 35);
            CGFloat newYPos = buttonFrame.origin.y + 9; // Change UIButton position
            buttonFrame.origin.y = newYPos;

            button.frame = buttonFrame;

            [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

            switch (button.tag)
            {
                case kFIRST_BUTTON:
                {

                    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"short_button_gold_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"short_button_gold_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
                }
                    break;
                case kSECOND_BUTTON:
                {
                    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"short_button_black_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"short_button_black_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
                }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    [self updateConstraints];
}
```

Result:

[image: No text on the button]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means you just want to add Title on UIButton?

Try This -

```
  [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"short_button_gold_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [button setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: There is no need to 'setTitle' as it inherit from the definition itself.

Comment: What do you mean by "There is no need to 'setTitle' as it inherit from the definition itself?"

Comment: When you do: NAlertView *customAlert = [[NAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:@"cancel", nil];
[customAlert show]; ---> the 'initWithTitle' set the title by itself, therefore there is no need to set the title.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"short_button_gold_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

to

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"short_button_gold_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

change all such possibilities.

and use the below method to change the text of the button

```
[button setTitle:@"text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Hope it helps.